# Pointer being freed was not allocated for array of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that this question exists in other places like:

[pointer being freed was not allocated in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540414/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-in-c)
[error: pointer being freed was not allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487870/error-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated)

but, I'm still very confused. Errors seem to be associated with things like "modifying the original pointer returned by malloc" and "failing to malloc before freeing". I just don't see how these reasons apply to my program.

I'm writing a dynamically allocated array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NLETTERS 25

typedef struct {
    char** array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} array_t;

array_t* initArray(size_t initialSize) {
    array_t* a = malloc(sizeof(array_t));
    a->array = malloc(initialSize*sizeof(char*));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < initialSize; i++) {
        a->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * NLETTERS);
    }

    return a;
}

void insertArray(array_t *a, char* element) {
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;

        a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char*));

        int i;
        for(i = (int)a->used; i < a->size; i++) {
            a->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * NLETTERS);
        }
    }
    a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void freeArray(array_t *a) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
        free(a->array[i]);
    }

    free(a->array);
    free(a);
    a->array = NULL;
    a->used = a->size = 0;
}

void print_array(array_t *a) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a->array[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    array_t *a;
    a = initArray(2);
    insertArray(a, "hello");
    insertArray(a, "how are you");
    print_array(a);
    insertArray(a, "yup");
    insertArray(a, "you know it");
    print_array(a);

    freeArray(a);

    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to "free", I get the error: "pointer being freed was not allocated" 
right at

```
free(a->array[0])
```

in the first iteration of the for-loop in freeArray();

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you suggesting that my realloc is incorrect? What should it change to? I'm not really understanding what the fix is under that link.

Comment: Note that in `insertArray()`, you have the idiom `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);`.  This is bad.  If (when!) `realloc()` fails, you leak memory because the `old_ptr` is over-written with NULL, so you can no longer free the old memory, even though it is still allocated.  Use `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == NULL) { …report error, etc… } old_ptr = new_ptr;` (and usually also `old_size = new_size;` too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, by saying

```
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
```

you're overwriting the allocated memory by `malloc()`, so, later while passing it to `free()` causes the issue.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3, *The `free` function*, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

Also, at a later point, this causes [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), as the memory allocated by `malloc()` is not getting `free()`-d, actually.

**Solution:** You should use [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to *copy* the content *into* the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is the line:

```
a->array[a->used++] = element;
```

It has two problems:

1. It leaks memory. The memory returned by `malloc()` is lost.
2. It points to read only memory used for string literals, which causes problems when you call `free` on it.

Replace that line with

```
strcpy(a->array[a->used++], element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues :-

1. `a->array[a->used++] = element;`
   You have allocated memory but inplace of using that, you are again pointing it to some other location resulting in memory leak. So change it to :-

   strcpy(a->array[a->used++], element);
2. Change `FreeArray` like this (you are freeing memory and than using it, which is resulting in seg fault).

   ```
   void freeArray(array_t *a) {
       int i;
       for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
           free(a->array[i]);
       }

       free(a->array);
       a->array = NULL;
       a->used = a->size = 0;
       free(a);
   }
   ```